# Ignite FileAlreadyExistsException during WAL Archival

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are using Gridgain Version: 8.8.10
JDK Version: 1.8

We have Ignite cluster with 3 nodes in Azure Kubernetes. We have enabled native persistence. Some of our Ignite pods are going into the CrashLoopBackOff with the below exception

```
[07:45:45,477][WARNING][main][FileWriteAheadLogManager] Content of WAL working directory needs rearrangement, some WAL segments will be moved to archive: /gridgain/walarchive/node00-71fcf5d3-faf7-4d2b-abae-bd0621bb12a1. Segments from 0000000000000001.wal to 0000000000000008.wal will be moved, total number of files: 8. This operation may take some time.
[07:45:45,480][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start processor: GridProcessorAdapter []
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1938)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1159)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1787)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1711)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1059)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:945)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:844)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:683)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:344)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:290)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.StorageException: Failed to move WAL segment [src=/gridgain/wal/node00-71fcf5d3-faf7-4d2b-abae-bd0621bb12a1/0000000000000001.wal, dst=/gridgain/walarchive/node00-71fcf5d3-faf7-4d2b-abae-bd0621bb12a1/0000000000000001.wal]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.moveSegmentsToArchive(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:3326)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.prepareAndCheckWalFiles(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:1542)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.start0(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.start(GridCacheSharedManagerAdapter.java:60)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.start(GridCacheProcessor.java:605)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1935)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /gridgain/walarchive/node00-71fcf5d3-faf7-4d2b-abae-bd0621bb12a1/0000000000000001.wal
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:267)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1422)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.moveSegmentsToArchive(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:3307)
    ... 16 more
[07:45:45,482][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
```

It seems like the during WAL Archival it is created file with the same name and it is not able to override the file. Is the any specific configuration during WAL Archival which we are missing?

```
 <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <!-- set the size of wal segments to 128MB -->
                <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{128 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
                <!-- Set the page size to 8 KB -->
                <property name="pageSize" value="#{8 * 1024}"/>
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="Default_Region"/>
                        <!-- Memory region of 20 MB initial size. -->
                        <property name="initialSize" value="#{20 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <!-- Memory region of 8 GB max size. -->
                        <property name="maxSize" value="#{8L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        <!-- Enabling eviction for this memory region. -->
                        <property name="pageEvictionMode" value="RANDOM_2_LRU"/>
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                        <!-- Increasing the buffer size to 1 GB. -->
                        <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{1024L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="walPath" value="/gridgain/wal"/>
                <property name="walArchivePath" value="/gridgain/walarchive"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
```

Anyone has faced a similar issue with Ignite Kubernetes Cluster.

We are observing this in GKE. In AKS it works fine. We are using the Apache Ignite Operator.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/gke-deployment

Comment: WAL segments in archive folder should not be overridden. They should be unique. Be sure, you have a separate folder for WAL archive for each node.

Comment: Yes, I have check the files name in both WAL and WALArchive both the getting created with same name. Also you can see my config above both of them are in different path.

Comment: Maybe you did not understand my point. Be sure your different nodes does not use the same directory (may be it is some shared network volume) for WAL archive. WAL archive should be placed in separete directory for each node. I asked it, because according your stacktrace,  you already have a file in WAL archive directory, but all files in WAL archive directory are uniq and does not rewrited.

Comment: We have mounted the volume for WAL and Work directory for Ignite Cluster. We have used separate disks for each node. The issue is happening during Wal Archival when it tries to copy the file from WAL to WALArchive. When we turned off the Wal Archieval  it is working fine.